# ocLazyload not loading the module

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload

In html I am loading the oclazyload before my app.js -

```
<!-- inject:js -->
        <script src="/packages/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/packages/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/packages/libs/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
        <script src="/packages/libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <!-- endinject -->

        <script src="app/app.js" ></script>
        <script src="app/common/app.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

My app.js -

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyload']);

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });
})();
```

But for some reason it doesn't load the `oc.lazyload` module at all . what might be the problem ?  Am I missing something ?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module oc.lazyload due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'oc.lazyload' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a typo. The module name is camel case. Change

```
'oc.lazyload'
```

to

```
'oc.lazyLoad' //'L' capitalized
```

Answer (score 1):

The dependency for oc lazyload should be added as `oc.lazyLoad` instead of `oc.lazyload`

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad']);

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });
})();
```

[**Reference**](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/blob/master/examples/simpleExample/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error, even though I did not have any typos and I followed the configuration directions at https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs.  I was using Angular within Ruby on Rails, and my error was fixed by adding the line below to my **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** file:

```
//= require oclazyload
```