# Lazyload not loading the module

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add in **lazyload** in module, by its showing ***error***:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'lazyLoad' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies 
as the second argument.
```

my code is `"angular.module('nouveau', ['lazyLoad'])"`

even i have tried with `"angular.module('nouveau', ['lazyload'])"` after watching [ocLazyload not loading the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980814/oclazyload-not-loading-the-module.but) not working!!!

```
"client/bower_components/angular-lazyload/src/angular-lazyload.js"
```

can any one help me???

Comment: The name of the module is `oc.lazyLoad`

Comment: on-lazy load is different module.. i am trying with https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-lazyload

Comment: Open your console and check if the script is loaded

Answer (score 0):

replace `angular.module('nouveau', ['lazyLoad'])`

in your code with

`angular.module('nouveau', ['oc.lazyLoad'])`

Hope it solves your issue. Cheers.. :)

Comment: angular.module('nouveau', ['oc.lazyLoad']), replace angular.module('nouveau', ['lazyLoad']), both are  different